For which $c \in \mathbb{C}$ does multi-valued function $\sqrt{e^z -c}$ define 2 single-valued functions?

For which $c \in \mathbb{C}$ does multi-valued function  $\sqrt{e^z -c}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ define 2 single-valued functions?

I guessed that $\sqrt{e^z -c}$ is single-valued iff $c = 0$, for if $c = 0$ then $\sqrt{e^z}$ splits into 2 single-valued functions $e^{z/2}$ and $-e^{z/2}$, and if $c \neq 0$ then $e^z - c = 0$ at $z = \log c$, here I supposed $z = \log c$ be a branch point and $\sqrt{e^z -c}$ be multi-valued.
I tried to show that by making analytic continuation along a path around $z = \log c$, but I found a path around $z = \log c$ does not make a path around $0$. So there may be another solution to solve this.
Can someone give me a hint?

Welcome to MSE! <> Your guess is good, assuming the question can be interpreted as, "For which complex $c$ does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(z)^{2} = \exp(z) - c$ for all $z$?" The conceptual point is, if $\exp(z_0) - c = 0$ for some $z_0$, then $g(z) = \exp(z) - c$ has a simple root at $z_0$ (why?), so there is no (holomorphic) branch of $\sqrt{\exp(z) - c}$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$. That is how I personally would approach writing a careful argument.
